# Terraform version not being adhered to

Tags: terraform

I am checking out a `terraform` module and also specifying the `terraform` `helm` provider version as follows

```
provider helm {
    enable_tls = true
    install_tiller  = "false"
    version = "~>0.10.3"
}

module "my-module" {
  source = "../"
}
```

However when viewing the version, I get another version for the `helm` provider (which also seem to be the latest)

```
+ provider.google v2.20.1
+ provider.helm v0.10.4
+ provider.kubernetes v1.10.0
+ provider.null v2.1.2
+ provider.template v2.1.2
```

Why is that?

**edit** however running `terraform providers` shows the correct version

```
.
├── provider.helm ~>0.10.3
└── module.my-module
    ├── provider.google
    ├── provider.helm (inherited)
    ├── provider.kubernetes
    ├── provider.null
    └── provider.template
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `~>` version constraint is the "pessimistic constraint operator" which allows upgrades to the narrowest specified version.

The [Terraform settings block documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/terraform.html#specifying-a-required-terraform-version) explains version constraints in more detail:

The following constraint operators are allowed:

> - = (or no operator): exact version equality
> - !=: version not equal
> - >, >=, <, <=: version comparison, where "greater than" is a larger version number
> - ~>: pessimistic constraint operator, constraining both the oldest and newest version allowed. For example, ~> 0.9 is equivalent to >=
>     0.9, < 1.0, and ~> 0.8.4, is equivalent to >= 0.8.4, < 0.9